# 'Which' in German

Tags: pronoun

Could you tell me, friends, how I am supposed to say the following which's in those sentences in German? That is, how to say the *which* that is referring to a certain sentence in German.

1. My dad got wasted again yesterday, which I was not happy about.
2. My teacher said that I had to make a presentation, which immediately drove me crazy.

Answer (score 5):

The second example is easier, because the fact from the main sentence just becomes the grammatical subject of the subordinate clause. In that case we just use *was* for *which* in German:

> My teacher said that I had to make a presentation, which immediately drove me crazy.
> Mein Lehrer sagte, dass ich eine Präsentation halten muss, **was** mich sofort wahnsinnig machte.

In the first example it's a bit more complicated because, in the subordinate clause, "which" isn't the subject, but instead actually part of the "about" prepositional.

A general recipe for a translation of this kind of *which*-clauses to German is to first translate the two clauses as if they were two full sentences. Doing that, you get a pronoun like "das" or a *Pronominaladverb* ("pronoun adverb") like *darauf, darüber, darunter, daran, dabei* etc. in the second sentence that refers back to the fact in the first sentence.

> My dad got wasted again yesterday. I was not happy **about that**.
> Mein Vater hat sich gestern betrunken. Ich war nicht glücklich **darüber**.

> My teacher said that I had to make a presentation. **That** immediately drove me crazy.
> Mein Lehrer sagte, dass ich eine Präsentation halten muss. **Das** machte mich sofort wahnsinning.

> My teacher said that I had to make a presentation. I immediately reported **that** to my friend.
> Mein Lehrer sagte, dass ich eine Präsentation halten muss. **Das** *[accusative object]* habe ich gleich meiner Freundin erzählt.

Then, the way to convert the second sentence back into a subordinate clause is to replace the pronoun or Pronominaladverb ("das" or "darüber") with the corresponding interrogative ("was", "worüber") and use the word order of a subordinate clause:

> Mein Vater hat sich gestern betrunken, **worüber** ich nicht glücklich war.

> Mein Lehrer sagte, dass ich eine Präsentation halten muss, **was** mich sofort wahnsinning machte.
> Mein Lehrer sagte, dass ich eine Präsentation halten muss, **was** ich gleich meiner Freundin erzählt habe.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, *which* translates to *worüber* because the relevant verb phrase in the dependent clause is ***über etwas** glücklich/traurig sein*, and it has the role of that prepositional object.

In the second example, *which* translates to *was* because it has the role of the subject in the dependent clause.

Comment: Perhaps you should write down the complete translation of the sentences.

Comment: But maybe it is *darüber* in the first sentence, as the sentence is affirmative, not negative?

Comment: I had not given a translation for the very purpose of not answering a translation request. Those are off-topic.

Comment: You can use *darüber* if you want to phrase it as two consecutive main clauses instead of a main clause and a dependent clause. The meaning is the same. It doesn't depend on affirmative vs negative.

Comment: It's not the *which* alone which translates to *worüber* but *which ... about*.